# [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I get that warning when I try to pass variables that should increment for each bar-widget.

The result I see is good (4,5,6), but it's not good when I check values with Vue Devtools extension, it says 307, 308, 309.

```
Vue.component('r-widget', {
  data(){
    return {
        uniqueIdNew: 3          
    }
  },
  methods: {
    unid(){
        this.uniqueIdNew++;
        return this.uniqueIdNew;
    }
  },
  template: '
     <div>
         <bar-widget :uniqueId=unid()></bar-widget>
         <bar-widget :uniqueId=unid()></bar-widget>
         <bar-widget :uniqueId=unid()></bar-widget>
     </div>
   '
});

Vue.component('bar-widget', {
  props: ['uniqueId'],
  template: '<div>{{uniqueId}}</div>'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#root'
});
```

Comment: This is probably because in your method you change the `uniqueIdNew`, which is a reactive property and may trigger updates of the previous widgets which in their turn will modify it and so on.. Not sure.. But why don't you let the method `unid()` simply return random string: `'id' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Slim Using random string was my plan B :) I wanted to see how to make it work this way, mostly for learning purposes.